# Получение JSON со страницы сайта

Tags: android, json, pojo

У меня есть приложение, которое выводит на карту отметки, координаты для которых я должен брать с сайта, где хранятся json объекты в таком виде и ничего больше нет.

```
[["2019-06-28T07:33:03", 37.610225, 55.651365], ["2019-06-28T07:33:18", 37.610225, 55.651365], ["2019-06-28T07:33:38", 37.610225, 55.651365] ... ]]
```

Мне нужно вывести их в POJO, никак не могу понять, как это сделать. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: По идее это будет массив массивов строк

Comment: как вы делаете запрос? У вас есть моделька которая описывает структуры этого респонса?

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko мне выслали тестовое задание и сказали брать значение с сайта, где только такое содержание и всё. Больше ничего. Спасибо за интерес, но я уже отказался от задания.